# Undefined reference to `WinMain@16' using C++17 standard

Tags: c++

Here's my header file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 void DateCheck (const int &XX, const int &YY, const int &ZZZZ)
{
    if (XX>=01 && XX<=31 && (YY==1 || YY==3 ||YY==5 ||YY==7 ||YY==8 ||YY==10 
||YY==12))
    cout<<"DATE ACCECPTABLE";
else if (XX>=01 && XX<=30 && (YY==4 ||YY==6 ||YY==9 ||YY==11))
    cout<<"DATE ACCECPTABLE";
else if (XX>=01 && XX<=29 && (YY==2 && ZZZZ%4==0))
    cout<<"DATE ACCECPTABLE";
else if (XX>=01 && XX<=28 && (YY==2 && ZZZZ%4!=0))
    cout<<"DATE ACCECPTABLE";
else
    cout<<"INVALID DATE";
}
```

and here's my C++ code snipet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "DateCheck.h"

using namespace std;


class Admission
{
    struct AdminFormat
    {
        char Name[30], FName[30], MName[30], Gender[10];
        char BG[2],d;
        static unsigned int DD, MM, YYYY;
        char FOccu[20], MOccu[20], Religion[10];
        char OffAddr[100], ResAddr[100], PermAddr[100];
        float DistSch;
        unsigned int Contact, EmpCode;
        int caste, stucat, Class;  ///7cast
        char Nationality[20];
        AdminFormat *next;
    }*st;
    AdminFormat *F, *R;
public:
    Admission ()
    {
        F=R=NULL;
    }
    void NewStu ();  ///admission of new student
    void TransfStu ();   ///transfer
    void Register ();   ///displaying records of students
    void Store ();   ///storing all records in a binary file
};

void Admission::Register ()
{
    Admission ad;
    ifstream i;
    i.open("Register.dat", ios::app|ios::binary);
   while (i.read((char*)&ad, sizeof ad))
{
    cout<<"Hello";
}
i.close();
}
```

I'm stuck here as I am unable to figure out why there's an error showing undefined reference to `WinMain@16`. It would be very nice of you if you people could debug my problem.
I have made the script using Codeblocks IDE and using gnu g++ compiler.

Comment: Looks like you are missing ``WinMain`` entry point function for your Windows app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows, a GUI application needs a function `WinMain`, and a console application needs a function `main`. Otherwise the OS wouldn't know where to start executing a program (OK, it's a bit more complicated than that, but that's all you need to know.)

A more helpful error message would be "Program requires an entry point (WinMain or main)".

Answer (score 1):

Any C++ program(with executable output) need a start point which is [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) function and for windows GUI application probably [`WinMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point) function. So either way you need to have one entry(start) point to your program (How can you start without start point?).

I can't find start point in your code and you've got the error complaining about it, so that should be the source of your problem.